# OSMDROID android 4.2: Mapquest: As of july 11,2016 direct tile access has been discontinued

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapquest

While using osmdroid. I get "As of july 11,2016 direct tile access has been discontinued." I think we have to use APIKEY to use this or a new sdk, but I don't find anywhere how to do it. Please help.

I am using OSMDROID 4.2 with OSMBonusPack_v5.0.
Please have a look at screen shot below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the tilesource from MapQuest. The easiest solution is to just use a different tilesource

```
    osmv.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
```

Comment: Is a simple solution for the moment. At least our clients can see a complete map layout...

Comment: Thanks, you save my life.